# Bash script waiting for forked child processes to complete

Tags: bash, loops, process, wait, child-process

I have a script that iterates through JPG files in folder structure processing them.

To speed things up I've forked the processing tasks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
SECONDS=0 #Start the clock!

myloop () {
    local run=$1
    jpeg-transform "$file"
    stripexif "$file"
    ...other commands...
}

find /user/dan/testjpgs -name '*.jpg' -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file
    do myloop "$run" & #fork myloop
    done    

duration=$SECONDS
echo "$(($duration / 60)) minutes and $(($duration % 60)) seconds elapsed."
```

The problem is that the duration calculation at the end of the script is happening immediately after the script is executed. It's not waiting for the child processes to complete and just returns 'Zero seconds elapsed'.

I've tried inserting a "wait" command after the do...done loop but it doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using the GNU parallel command, works great and also scales child processes to the number of available CPU cores. I'm sure it could have been done in pure bash but but this look more elegant to me.

```
#!/bin/sh
SECONDS=0 #Start the clock!

myloop () {
    command
    command
    command
}
export -f myloop

find . -name '*.jpg' | parallel myloop {}

duration=$SECONDS
echo "$(($duration / 60)) minutes and $(($duration % 60)) seconds elapsed."
```